# How to make a candle smoke shader?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to simulate smoke rising from a candle, and was trying to find a way to make a volumetric shader that works on Cycles.

I found a tutorial for something similar that works on 2d planes using texture coordinates and a noise texture. Looks like this: [image]

But I needed something similar that worked for a cube instead, so I can better get the 3d volume to feed into the Density of a Volumetric Shader. Any ideas for an alternative?

Comment: What kind of alternative you are looking for? Lowering rendering time?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after some headaches, I think i found a solution, which was basically doing everything two times, for X and Y.

[image]

Looks something like this: [image]

You can control the shape via the Noise Texture. And animate it by using the mapping node. The only problem is that the end shape is somewhat diagonal, so if anyone know a better implementation, or any other improvements let me know.